# How to make a curry version of map that always returns list using toolz

Tags: python, toolz

If I import toolz using

```
from toolz.curried import *
```

then `map` will automatically becomes curried form, so

```
map(func,[[1,2],[3,4]])
```

can be written as

```
map(func)([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

but curried `map` always return an iterable. I way to define an curried `lmap` which always return list. But simple try

```
lmap=compose(list,map)
```

will not work, for example

```
lmap(len)([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

will give

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  TypeError Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 lmap(len)([[1,2],[3,4]])
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\toolz\functoolz.py in
>   **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       466         ret = self.first(*args, **kwargs)
>       467         for f in self.funcs:
>   --> 468             ret = f(ret)
>       469         return ret
>       470
>
> TypeError: 'curry' object is not iterable

So how to define a curried `lmap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling it wrong way. `map` being passed to compose is curried, but not a whole expression. When you call it like

```
lmap(len)([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

it passes `len` to `lmap` it returns `toolz.functoolz.curry` equivalent to

```
map(len)
```

and then tries to call `list` on it:

```
list(map(len))
```

which obviously cannot work. If it didn't fail complete expression would be equivalent to:

```
list(map(len))([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

while the call you're looking for is:

```
list(map(len), [[1,2],[3,4]])
```

So in fact currying doesn't make much sense here.

You probably want something around these lines:

```
def lmap(g): return compose(list, map(g))
```

which would be callable as you want:

```
>>> lmap(len)([[1,2],[3,4]])
[2, 2]
```

but to honest the problem looks a bit artificial - the biggest advantage of `toolz` in uniform laziness. Converting to `list` throws away most of that.

Answer (score 1):

This question is currently top in google results for the toolz error `'curry' object is not iterable`. One additional way to trigger this error message not yet mentioned here is to attempt to use `toolz.curried.pipe` with curried iterators as if `pipe` itself were curried:

```
>>> transform = pipe(
    map(lambda x: x + 1),
    map(lambda x: x + x)
    )
>>> list(transform([3,4,5]))
TypeError: 'curry' object is not iterable
```

Here the first curried map is being passed as the final argument to the second;
despite being reexported from the curried namespace, pipe is not curried. The solution is to upgrade to toolz version 0.10.0 if not already using it and use `toolz.curried.compose_left` instead which is effectively a curried `pipe`:

```
>>> transform = compose_left(
    map(lambda x: x + 1),
    map(lambda x: x + x)
    )
>>> list(transform([3,4,5]))
[8, 10, 12]
```

Comment: While this may be useful for someone who googled that error, it does not really answers the question. It's just some information unrelated to this particular question.

Comment: Since this doesn't directly answer OP's question, it might get deleted at some point via peer review. Personally I would hate to see this info get deleted since it seems pretty useful. @qwitwa I suggest that you post this as a new question, answer+accept it yourself, then link to your new post in a comment on this question.